# Slicing a matrix by an index matrix in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an n-by-m matrix X and an n-by-r index matrix I. I am wondering what are the relevant TensorFlow operators that allow me to get an n-by-r matrix R such that R[i,j] = X[i,I[i,j]]. As an example, let's say

```
X = tf.constant([[1,2,3],
                [4,5,6],
                [7,8,9]])

I = tf.constant([[1,2],
                 [1,0],
                 [0,2]])
```

The desired result would be a tensor

```
R = [[2, 3], 
     [5, 4],
     [7, 9]]
```

I tried to use each column of the matrix I as the index and do tf.diag_part(tf.gather(X', index)), which seems to give me one column of R if I has the same number of row as X. For example,

```
idx = tf.transpose(I)[0] #[1,1,0]
res = tf.diag_part(tf.gather(tf.transpose(X), idx))

# res will be [2,5,7], i,e, first colum of R
```

Another attempt:

```
res = tf.transpose(tf.gather(tf.transpose(X), I),[0,2,1])
print(res.eval()) 
        array([[[2, 3],
                [5, 6],
                [8, 9]],

               [[2, 1],
                [5, 4],
                [8, 7]],

               [[3, 1],
                [6, 4],
                [7, 9]]], dtype=int32)
```

From here i just need to be able to select the "diagonal entries" res[0,0], res[1,1] and res[2,2] to get R. I get stuck here though...

Comment: Can you provide your attempt with `tf.gather`?

Comment: @jakub I tried to use each row of the matrix I as the index and do tf.diag_part(tf.gather(X', index)), which seems to give me one row of R. but i don't know how to aggregate everything together...

Comment: Can you please add your attempt to your question? It will be easier to help if we know what you tried.

Comment: @jakub i made an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tf.gather` with `batch_dims` argument:

```
res = tf.gather(X, I, batch_dims=1)
```

Comment: Great! I was able to get the result with                                                                           
(1) res = tf.gather(tf.transpose(X), I)
(2) res = tf.transpose(res, [1,2,0])
(3) res = tf.transpose(tf.linalg.diag_part(res))